# Ruby: cannot resolve dependencies for win32 package

Tags: ruby, package

I just installed win32-clibpoard for Ruby but it does not work because of a highly descriptive message `RubyGem version error: win32-api(1.4.5 not >= 0)`.

Help needed.

```
C:> gem install win32-clipboard                           
Successfully installed win32-clipboard-0.5.2              
1 gem installed                                           
Installing ri documentation for win32-clipboard-0.5.2...  
Installing RDoc documentation for win32-clipboard-0.5.2...

c:/ruby19/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:926:in `report_activate_error': RubyGem version error: win32-api(1.4.5 not >= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
        from c:/ruby19/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:244:in `activate_dep'                             
        from c:/ruby19/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:236:in `activate'                                 
        from c:/ruby19/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:213:in `rescue in try_activate'                   
        from c:/ruby19/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:210:in `try_activate'                             
        from c:/ruby19/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:56:in `rescue in require'          
        from c:/ruby19/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'                    
        from c:/ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/windows-api-0.4.0/lib/windows/api.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'  
        from c:/ruby19/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `require'                    
        from c:/ruby19/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `require'                    
        from c:/ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/windows-pr-1.2.1/lib/windows/clipboard.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/ruby19/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `require'                    
        from c:/ruby19/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `require'                    
        from c:/ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/win32-clipboard-0.5.2/lib/win32/clipboard.rb:1:in `<top (required)>' 
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:33:in `require'                                           
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:33:in `rescue in require'                                 
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'                                           
        from files2tracks.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should uninstall the actual gem win32-api, just execute `gem uninstall win-32-api`
and then proceed with:

1 Download the gem from http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/62628/win32-api-1.4.5-x86-mswin32-60.gem

2 And install it locally with:
`gem install win32-api-1.4.5-x86-mswin32-60.gem`

3 and then try:
`gem install win32-clipboard`